# Bad html5 application view size on iphone

Tags: ios, html, resize

I just got an html5 app with code that needs to be deployed to an iphone but the sizing seems to be totally messed up (it's like 4 times of the entire screen). As I have very little experience with html5 I'd like to ask, is there something else that needs to be set for the page to correctly fit onto a screen besides adding the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

line in the index.html file?